# Enable Both Microsoft Authentication (OpenID) and Custom Username Password authentication in .Net Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, openid, identity

I'm implementing both Custom Authentication (for External Users) and Microsoft Authentication (for Internal Users).
This is a .net 4.7.2 framework webform project.

I have added a startup.cs to the project.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AppModelv2_WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Startup))]

namespace AppModelv2_WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet
{
  public class Startup
  {  
   string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure Forms Authentication for custom authentication
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
        });

        // Configure OpenIdConnectAuthentication for Microsoft login
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
  }
}
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void btnInternal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    protected void btnExternal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Assume validation for username password against db is done

        string customUsername = "externaljohn";

        ClaimsIdentity customIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, customUsername),
        }, "Custom");

        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(customIdentity);

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Get the username
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            // Now you can use the 'username' variable as needed
            // For example, display it in a label on the page
            lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + username + "!";
        }
```

This is working fine with Microsoft login. When I click "Internal" button, it will redirect to Microsoft login page where I can enter my office 365 credentials and then it will navigate to Default.aspx page and show username correctly.

However, when I click "External" button, it will redirect to Default.aspx but HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false.

I haven't done any changes to web.config except adding the appettings for ClientId, Tenant, authority and redirectUri